# Как вернуть страничку через node.js

Tags: node.js

Как вернуть страничку через node.js. Надо использовать модуль fs и его метод open?

Comment: @Zow, я тут наткнулся на [интересную книжку](http://www.nodebeginner.ru/).

Почитайте, IMHO найдете в ней ответы на кучу своих Вопросов по node.js

Comment: @avp, я уже рекомендовал ее ТС в его предыдущем вопросе (ныне удаленном).

Comment: я не успел увидеть, сорри @Nofate, а удалять нельзя? то я просто если понял благодаря тебе, а ответов не было, то зачем форум забивать

Comment: так я ее прочел уже, вот дальше начал читать документацию, тока она как-то мозаично написана, что понять не все могу

Comment: > просто если понял благодаря тебе

Тогда можно попросить модераторов превратить комментарий в ответ и поблагодарить ответившего плюсиком/лучшим ответом.

Comment: ок, в следующий разы буду так делать

Comment: @Zow, лучше без особых причин вопросы (и ответы) с форума не удалять. Таким образом здесь накапливается некая "база знаний". 

По вопросу может в разных ответах и комментариях возникнуть обмен мнениями и советами среди участников форума и их уревень понимания IT возрастет. 

В общем, в подобных случаях не стоит экономить дисковое пространство и циклы процессора.

Comment: @avp - как по мне, книга не особо удалась, особенно, на мой взгляд, она противопоказана начинающим разработчикам ( не на Node.js, а вообще )

Comment: Может быть. Я ее еще не прочитал. Только посмотрел начало. 

Мне понравилось, что автор сразу берет "быка за рога".

    var http = require("http");
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("Hello World");
      response.end();
    }).listen(8888);

А потом на этом примере показывает как усторен JS.

Comment: @avp - "быка за рога" берет и офф.сайт node.js ;)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, а чем вам та книжка не понравилась? Отличный учебник, для нода такое нечасто встречается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит делать это вручную (читать из фс и т.п.). Предлагаю воспользоваться web-фреймворком [express](http://express-js.ru/). По ссылке вы и узнаете как решить вашу задачу.

Если коротко:

- инициализировать сервер
- добавить обратботчик url-а
- отрендерить страницу шаблонизатором

Причем это займет всего несколько строчек. Что-то вроде:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var model = { title : { main: "hello world!", subtitle: "subtitle" }, layout: false };
    res.render('index.jade', model);        
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Данный код создает web-сервер, слушающий 80й порт и возвращающий страницу на основе шаблона `index.jade` из директории `static`.

NB: Сложно изучить технологию с ноля только задавая вопросы на форумах. Проштудируйте упомянутые в этом топике руководства и мы сможем общаться на одном языке.

Comment: Зачем тут фреймворк? К тому-же польза реймворков в node.js крайне сомнительна т.к., по сути, фреймворк это тупо сборка независмых модулей.

PS: ИМХО - jade УГ.

Comment: *Не стоит делать это вручную* - почему? Вера не позволяет? :)
****
офф версия node.js, установленная с помощью `npm install dust` - не работает и требует небольших правок, рабочая версия под последнюю стабильную версию node.js [здесь](http://sandp.alexwindhope.com/dust.zip)

Comment: Вера позволяет все, что угодно ). Вопрос в целесообразности. Если можно решить задачу в пару строчек - почему бы не решить ее в пару строчек. Особенно новичку. Как освоится и проникнется, сможет сам решить, какого вкуса и цвета велосипеды себе писать.

---
> jade УГ (особенно синтаксис шаблонов)

Кому как. Синхронность, конечно, минус, но синтаксис именно разметки мне, например, по нраву.

Comment: Извольте - причем тут велосипеды? Или для вас задача "прочитать содержимое файла" строго для великого гуру и новичку неподвластная?
****
К тому-же, вы меня не совсем верно поняли. Велосипедить практически не приходиться, нужно просто самому выбрать те модули, которые больше подходят именно вам или вашей команде, в сумме получиться практически готовый фреймворк( как минимум готовая база ), добавляем немного синтаксического сахара, пишем свои модули( если в этом есть необходимость, чаше всего ее нет ), обворачиваем все это в единую сущность и вуаля - на выходе именно то, что нужно именно вам.

Comment: > Или для вас задача "прочитать содержимое файла" строго для великого гуру

Видите ли, этот топик является продолжением ранее начатого с @Zow разговора. Речь идет не о возвращении странички как таковой, а о создании сферического веб-приложения. ИМХО c express быстрее и проще почувствовать вкус веб-разработки на node.js.

Настаивать не буду ) Выбирать автору.

Comment: @Nofate - на самом деле я могу быть крайне неадекватным, просто я, мягко говоря, не являюсь фанатом express и вообще не вижу смысла, в контексте node.js, в "фреймворке" ( читай наборе модулей с синтаксическим сахаром ).

Но с т.з. продакшина я, пожалуй, соглашусь, а вот с т.з. обучения, на мой взгляд, однозначно не стоит браться за фреймворк, если ты, даже примерно, не представляешь как он работает.

В итоге получиться примерно такой-же "разработчик", как те товарищи, способности которых заканчиваются на прикручивании jq модулей :)

PS: редактирование комментариев так и не пофиксили, печаль..

Comment: Зато Sublime нам обоим нравится )

Comment: @Nofate, мне надо скачать еще Jade, его же вроде еще подключать надо?

Comment: Он в `express` "из коробки" наличествует, AFAIR

Answer (score 1):

собственно код простой до безобразия, никакого express тут в помине ненадо, всё прекрасно делается на нативном Node.js , и лично по мне в таком виде он красивее и понятнее.

```
'use strict';
var fs = require("fs");
var index = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
    res.end(index);
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Comment: Кроме косяка с отправкой html-страницы, когда браузер запросит иконку, всё хорошо. Я привёл ещё вариант, где файл читается каждый раз - это удобнее в случае разработки - не придётся сервер перезапускать при каждом изменении.

Comment: ну да, но с другой стороны страничка висит в памяти и нет запроса на диск, для обновления можно юзать fs.watchFile(); ну тут собственно он будет всегда отдавать картинку, даже если на страничке есть ссылки на css, jpg или js. можно сделать чтение по директории но это не секьюрно и помоему плохой стиль если это не нужно специально, так что привёл самый минимум кода :)

Comment: У всего свои плюсы и минусы. Если файл страницы должен формироваться на основе url, то это хардкодить все имена явно не хочется. В моём варианте можно сделать кеш, что файл помещается в память при первом обращении и там остаётся.

Answer (score 1):

В образовательных целях:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url);

  if (req.url === "/favicon.ico") {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
  fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```